# Statsmodels ETSModel different results from ExponentialSmoothing

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting

In the past I have set up an ETS Model, using ExponentialSmoothing, that has great results in a Forecast. However now I need confidence intervals, so I decided to swap to ETSModel.

I am now trying to get the same forecast results with the ETSModel, but even though the data and everything is the same, the results differ. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't both functions return the same results?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing

# Exponential Smoothing
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, trend='add', damped_trend=1, seasonal='add', seasonal_periods=120)
fit = model.fit(smoothing_level=0.0, smoothing_trend=0.6)
pred = fit.get_forecast(len(test))

# ETSModel
ets_model = ETSModel(
    endog=pd.Series(train),
    trend='add',
    damped_trend=0,
    seasonal='add',
    seasonal_periods=120
)

fit = ets_model.fit(smoothing_level=0.0, smoothing_trend=0.6, smoothing_seasonal=0.0, damping_trend=0.0)
pred = fit.forecast(len(test))
```

I have tried multiple parameters, looked up if some new parameters in the ETSModel are set by default but I cannot figure out why the results differ.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth comparing the RMSE scores for the predictions of both of your models relative to the test data.

As an example, I used the above two models on a separate dataset to forecast mean temperature. For comparison purposes, I set the damped trend to 0 in both cases as well as keeping other parameters the same.

**Imported libraries**

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing import ExponentialSmoothing
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
```

**Model 1**

```
>>> model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, trend='add', damped_trend=0, seasonal=12)
>>> fit = model.fit(smoothing_level=0.0, smoothing_trend=0.6)
>>> pred1 = fit.forecast(len(test))
>>> pred1

array([14.9385243 , 13.10477164, 10.52616329,  7.2273328 ,  5.87631237,
       ...
       14.99617795, 13.16242528])

>>> mse=sm.tools.eval_measures.mse(test, pred1, axis=0)
>>> mse
>>> rmse=math.sqrt(mse)
>>> rmse

2.2514312260896867
```

**Model 2**

```
>>> ets_model = ETSModel(
>>>     endog=pd.Series(train),
>>>     trend='add',
>>>     damped_trend=0,
>>>     seasonal='add',
>>>     seasonal_periods=12
>>> )

>>> fit = ets_model.fit(smoothing_level=0.0, smoothing_trend=0.6, smoothing_seasonal=0.0, damping_trend=0.0)
>>> pred2 = fit.forecast(len(test))
>>> pred2

729    15.052551
730    13.214303
         ...    
909    15.154241
910    13.315993

>>> mse=sm.tools.eval_measures.mse(test, pred2, axis=0)
>>> mse
>>> rmse=math.sqrt(mse)
>>> rmse

2.262309478131116
```

As we can see, the generated prediction arrays across the two models are not the same - but the RMSE generated for the two models are virtually identical - indicating that the predictive power of the two models are the same.

It is not uncommon for prediction results across two models to not be completely exact - I note that the first model is imported from `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing`. The [guide](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing.html) states that the model is expected to perform slightly worse than that of the dedicated exponential smoothing model - as the exponential smoothing equations are set up "as a special case of a linear Gaussian state space model", with a Kalman filter applied. As the results are based on the filtered output from the state space models - it simply means that Model 2 is not using a state space model to make forecasts and thus why the results differ.

However, as mentioned - my ultimate recommendation is to compare prediction performance across the test set with RMSE to determine which model ultimately performs better.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have already compared the errors of both models, and the ETSModel is performing way worse than the ExponentialSmoothing one. Unfortunately i cannot share the data, but the MAE doubles

Comment: Acknowledged. In that regard, I cannot diagnose further - my example above demonstrated virtually identical performance so I cannot say why performance across the two models differs vastly in your case.